# Uncaught Error: Using $this when not in object context

Tags: magento-1.9, event-observer, fatal-error, helper, dispatch

I am going through an older module created in PHP 5.x.x and we have just moved the website to the php 7.2.x so we suddenly got the error in a helper class

```
Uncaught Error: Using $this when not in object context in
```

There is a dispatch event in helper that is using the following code there:

```
Mage::dispatchEvent('magento_string_filter_before', array('content' => $contentObj, 'object' => $params['object'], 'params' => $params, 'helper' => $this));
```

and i believe that is not compatible with the PHP 7 so how i can convert this and what replacement we have?

Thanks!

Comment: Are you trying to pass the object of current helper, right?

Comment: Yes you are right!

Comment: You need to replace $this with your helper class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have pass the object of the helper as like

replacing $this with following:

```
Mage::getSingleton('my_helper_here');
```

and code looks like this now and working fine for.

```
Mage::dispatchEvent('magento_string_filter_after', array('content' => $contentObj, 'object' => $params['object'], 'params' => $params, 'helper' => Mage::getSingleton('my_helper_here')));
```